# Rails: How to get the model class name based on the controller class name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class HouseBuyersController < ...
  def my_method
    # How could I get here the relevant model name, i.e. "HouseBuyer" ?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

This will do it:

```
class HouseBuyersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @model_name = controller_name.classify
  end

end
```

This is often needed when abstracting controller actions:

```
class HouseBuyersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # Equivalent of @house_buyers = HouseBuyer.find(:all)
    objects = controller_name.classify.constantize.find(:all)
    instance_variable_set("@#{controller_name}", objects)
  end

end
```

Comment: @model_name = controller_name.classify # returns "HouseBuyers" thanks!

Comment: Depending on your needs, (this question doesn't specify any details), you can do `controller_name.sub('_', ' ').titleize` to get "House Buyers".

Comment: It might be good to move the logic (for getting the model class) into a separate utility method. Even better if the result is stored in a constant, to speed up access. You can use `new.controller_name.classify.constantize` in the class definition.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this will even work in the application controller depending on which controller inherits from it.

Comment: this solution doesn't work with namespaces. See my solution below.

Answer (score 46):

If your controller and model are in the same namespace, then what you want is

```
controller_path.classify
```

`controller_path` gives you the namespace; `controller_name` doesn't.

For example, if your controller is

```
Admin::RolesController
```

then:

```
controller_path.classify # "Admin::Role" # CORRECT
controller_name.classify # "Role"        # INCORRECT
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is more generally valid while containing the non-namespaced version as a sub-answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a hack, but if your model is named after your controller name then:

```
class HouseBuyersController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    @model_name = self.class.name.sub("Controller", "").singularize
  end
end
```

... would give you "HouseBuyer" in your @model_name instance variable.

Again, this makes a huge assumption that "HouseBuyersController" only deals with "HouseBuyer" models.

Answer (score 4):

For namespaces working:

```
def resource_class
 controller_path.classify.constantize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not work for me as my controller and model was namespaced. Instead, I came up with the following method:

```rb
def controllers_model
  (self.class.name.split('::')[0..-2] << controller_name.classify).join('::')
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible if you are using the default MVC, which your code doesn't seem to follow. Your controller seems to be a model but maybe you just got a type there. Anyway, controllers and models are fundamentally separated in Rails MVC so controllers cannot know which model they are associated with.

For example you could have a model named post. This can have a controller posts_controller or could have a controller like articles_controller. Rails only knows about models when you def the actual code in the controller such as

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @posts = Article.all
end
```

In rails standard controllers there is no way to know what the model is.