# Rails best practice for similar controllers/views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, dry

I'm writing an inventory management Rails app. I have `class Product < ActiveRecord::Base`, `class Foo < Product` and `class Bar < Product`. Foo and Bar have subtly different behavior, but using single-table inheritance is great for them.

The problem is with the controllers and views. Currently I have them *completely* separate, which works, but contains a ton of repeated code. One could literally be generated from the other by copying the two directories and replacing `@foo`, `@foos`, and `Foo` with `@bar`, `@bars`, and `Bar`. As I add new features, it's irritating to add them twice. And, of course, it's not the Rails Way to not DRY.

So what's the correct approach here? For the controllers...should I make a `ProductsController` and then just use metaprogramming magic to sub in either `Foo` or `Bar`? Or use inheritance? For the views, should I only have a products view, but use clever routing to make it look like I have separate (and RESTful) `/foos` and `/bars` paths?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell the difference between Foo and Bar. Also please provide a solid reason why you need two models instead of one. Thanks. The solution may vary according to your situation.

Comment: The difference lies in the way they generate their serial number, and the semantics of them being registered to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the controller inheritance would be a nice, clean and maintainable way to go. Define all the major logic in a base controller and replace any calls to objects with virtual methods that can be overridden in your inheriting controllers:

```
class Product < ApplicationController
  def resource
    nil
  end

  def new_resource
    nil
  end

  def do_something
    resource.do_something
  end

  def new
    @resource = new_resource
  end
end

class Foo < Product
  def resource
    @foo
  end

  def new_resource
    Foo.new
  end
end
```

Inheritance is very maintainable, very clean and clear, a good choice for this kind of work.

As for views, you could have a `shared` directory for all common view partials, which is another very common approach and allows you full RESTful control over the URLs with minimal fuss. If your objects also have similar methods then the view doesn't need to know what class it's dealing with.

In the controllers above a user visiting foos/new would initiate a call to new_resource which would build a new Foo instance and return it to the page as @resource.

```
#View:
<%= render 'shared/product_details', :locals => {:product => @resource} %>
```

Comment: I like the looks of this except for the `@` variables. I'd still like `@foo` and `@bar` to be available in the views. If this were Python I know how to override class variable access from a subclass, but research into doing this with Ruby has been...frustrating. Basically I'd like `@foo` to be an alias for `@product` and so forth. How do I do this?

Comment: The example in this answer shows a more generic way of abstracting controller actions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6770284/562557

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact same controller methods and views, you could move it to product - this way, you would have `Product`, `@product` and `@products`. Since it is `STI`, there are no ID repetitions on `Foo` and `Bar`, so member routes would also work. Also, since the models are different, the duck typing will take care of calling the correct method for each.

You can then move everything that is not repeated from both child models to  then specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's further clarification, I have my ideas now.

Model inheritance is good for other OOP languages but not necessary in Ruby. In this case the best solution in my opinion is to use Module.

You still need two models Foo and Bar which could even have different attributes.

Then, define the common methods for model and controller

```
# lib/product_model.rb
module ProductModel
  def product_method_a
  end

  def product_method_b
  end
end

# lib/product_controller.rb
module ProductController
  def show
    @obj = @model.constantize.find(params[:id])
    render 'products/show' # need to explicitly specify it because this is general 
  end

  def index
    @objs = @model.constantize.scoped
    render 'products/index' # need to explicitly specify it because this is general 
  end
end
```

Then, use these methods in Foo and Bar, and add custom methods as you like.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ProductModel

  def serial_number
    # Foo's way
  end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ProductModel

  def serial_number
    # Bar's way
  end
end
```

For controller.

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  @model = "foo"
  include ProductController
end


class BarsController < ApplicationController
  @model = "bar"
  include ProductController
end
```

For views, the ProductController has already defined them, just to use general matching variable names in views.

```
<%= @obj.title %>
```

Quite DRY, isn't it?

Comment: I actually used to do exactly that for the model, and later changed it. It seemed less object-oriented, and I also like that with STI I can do `Product.all` and treat things polymorphically.

Comment: @tsm, OOP does not only mean "inheritance". Ruby is more flexible at this point. `as_as_something` is very popular pattern in Rails. STI has its use cases but has many drawbacks, such as scattered null data, only parent in polymorphic, etc. Why not use better alternative when you have.