# How to call the model's where(...) method from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have two models: Client and Product

The "username" and "email" of Client should be "unique index", as "serialnumber" of Product

When the user is typing on the form field that is unique index, I have an onblur function that sends a request to the controller with the attribute name and attribute value. If a value exists, the user is immediately informed.

In ClientController, I wrote a function that checks if it's unique or not and returns -2 for error, -1 for not exists or a positive number (the id) if exists.

```
def unique  
  if params[:attrName].blank? or params[:attrValue].blank?
    id = "-2"
  else
    cli = Client.where("#{params[:attrName]} = '#{params[:attrValue]}'").first
    if cli != nil
      id = cli["id"]
    else
      id = "-1"
    end
  end

  render :json => {
    :id => id
  }
end
```

This is not good for many reasons (SQL Injection vulnerability, violation of DRY, as each controller would have basically the same method.

I'm thinking of writing the "unique" function inside ApplicationController, but as you saw above, I should be able to call "Client.where" if it's a client, or "Product.where" if it's a product. How can I build this function the most "generically" possible and the most securily? I'm thinking of raw SQL but I think this is a naive approach.

Comment: Is this your goal? "username" and "email" are combined into a "serial number" type unique index saved within the product table when a product is created. Your wish is make sure that if the same user tries to create another product, any product, they'll be stopped because that user name and email have been used before to create a product. And you are not using model active record relationships to accomplish any of this logic. Is this the case?

Comment: No. "username" and "email" have nothing to do with "Product". They are examples of "unique-index" attributes. It's like when you are creating an e-mail account, and as you type the desired e-mail, you get the feedback of it's availability instantaniously. That's because as you type, the email string is sent to the server and it checks if it already exists in the database. Please read @yez answer, as it shows what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be wise to avoid raw SQL for this.

Would this work?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def unique
    id = if params[:attrName].blank? || params[:attrValue].blank?
      -2
    elsif found = model_name.where(params[:attrName] => params[:attrValue]).take
      found.id
    else
      -1
    end

    render json: { id: id }
  end
end
```

You could put that in `application_controller.rb` then in both of your `ClientsController` and `ProductsController` you would define the `model_name` method:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def model_name
    Client
  end
end

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def model_name
    Product
  end
end
```

This will work but might not be ideal. You might want to let Rails do more of the work by using [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) to raise if a model exists or not and [strong params](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) for validating that the params you need are present.

Comment: You could further refine this by gleaning the model name from the controller name - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869917/rails-how-to-get-the-model-class-name-based-on-the-controller-class-name (i.e.`controller_name.classify.constantize`)

Comment: nice! I didn't know that a method could simply return a model, as you did in "def model_name ..."

Answer (score 1):

You can move this to a module and make it return an `ActiveRecord` relation. the advantage is later you can chain this with other `ActiveRecord relations` if you wish to, Something like (and note I have used `?` in my sql condition, instead of directing giving the param )

```
#module
module UniqueRecord
  module ClassMethods
     def unique(params)
       where(params)
     end
  end

  def self.included(receiver) 
    receiver.extend         ClassMethods
  end
end
```

and use it in your class

```
#client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UniqueRecord
end

#product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UniqueRecord
end
```

So now both of your classes has the method `unique` available.

you can create a hash from the keys and values you get, Ex: you could dynamically create a hash to search email like

```
hash = {email: 'same@email.com'}
```

and then call the method

```
Client.unique(hash)
```

and if you want to , you can call it by the class name string

```
'Client'.constantize.unique(hash)
```

one more thing, it better to return an array of objects (if found) or blank array (if not found) instead of -1, -2. that will make your api consistent. like

`Client.unique(hash).to_json`

Comment: I didn't fully understand. So, with this approach, how could I check if, for example, the attribute "email" of Client has a value like "example@example.com"? Would it be like this? "def unique(attrName, attrValue) ... end" and use it like " 'Client.constantize.unique('email', 'example@example.com' "?

Comment: nice! I'll try this too